# Python pandas - Module not imported when executing from php

Tags: python, php, pandas

I have two php scripts.  Both executes python3 file and both of them sends emails through sendgrid api and designed to email id's into a mysql database table.

In one of the files, I am writing the email ids into mysql through a php mysqli_query itself. Apart from this I am also sending the mails.  This works.  The initial few lines of this file looks as follows:

```
import argparse
import os
import sendgrid as sendgrid
from sendgrid import SendGridAPIClient
from sendgrid.helpers.mail import Mail
```

In the second file, I want to do some data realignment and hence, I have used `pandas` and `MySQLdb` to manipulate the data before writing to database.  The initial few lines of this file looks like this:

```
import os
import argparse
#import MySQLdb
#import pandas as pd
import sendgrid as sendgrid
from sendgrid import SendGridAPIClient
from sendgrid.helpers.mail import Mail


ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-f","--inputFile",required=True,help="name of the annotations file")
ap.add_argument("-c","--clientid",required=True,help="name of the operator")
```

In this script I am getting the `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MySQLdb'` and so is for `pandas`.  However, if I disable these two imports, the rest works fine.

I have installed both the libraries using:

```
sudo pip3 install pandas
sudo pip3 install mysql-client-dev (not sure about this path, but it works properly)
```

When I list packages using `sudo pip3 list` and `pip3 list` I can see all the packages including `sendgrid`, `pandas` and `mysqlclient`.  When I run from a python3 console, I could import all 3 packages without any trouble.

All the files in the path are owned by `www-data:www-data` and all the files have 777 rights.  Still whenever I run the script with `import pandas as pd` I get the module not found error.

Comment: Few things that I need clarification on:  (1) are there 4 scripts? 2 PHP scripts and 2 Python scripts? (2) are the PHP scripts calling calling the Python3 scripts? What else is happening in PHP? (3) related to previous question, you said `I am writing the email ids into mysql through a php mysqli_query itself. ` but then you are also importing `SendGrid` and `MySQL` libraries in Python. Are both python *and* php making these calls?  I'm really confused, it's hard to tell which script does what.

Comment: 1) yes, 4 scripts comprising of 2 php scripts - each calling two python scripts.  2) Yes. 3) First PHP script calls a python program that imports sendgrid, sends mails to email ids and saves those email ids into mysql and second php script calls second python program that  imports sendgrid,mysqldb,and pandas.  the second php script fails in importing pandas and mysqldb.  but both the python scripts work if i import only sendgrid.

Comment: I'm assuming `MySQLdb` and `pandas` are commented out in the second script for testing?

Comment: @z4-tier yes... They are commented for testing purposes

Answer (score 0):

This problem got resolved by installing the python packages globally.  To install a python package globally, for example, pandas, use

```
sudo -H pip3 install pandas
```

When I installed, all my programs started working instantly.  I was under the impression `sudo pip3 install pandas` will install at the root level and hence available globally, which was not the case.